# Find out the length of a recurrence

Tags: sequences-and-series, puzzle

I have this rules for creating a list of numbers:

1. $x/2$ if $x$ is even, repeat
2. $3x+1$ if $x$ is odd, repeat
3. if $x=1$, stop

so for example, starting from 15, the list will be: 15, 46, 23, 70, 45, 136, 68, 34, 17,  52, 26, 13, 40, 20, 10, 5, 16, 8, 4, 2, 1.

So, for a starting x = 15, the length of the list will be 21. How to find out the length for an arbitrary x?

Of course i'm looking for the most general approach, ie if i change one of the rule or if i add one rule more

Comment: Look up the "3n+1 conjecture".

Comment: uao! the rebus daily rebus semms to be more than a simple newspaper rebus.. so, it is an unresolved probleblem and no one know how to calculate it yet?

Comment: The simplest way I know of is to simply perform the procedure. There is no known closed form, since it is not known in general whether the list is even finite.

Comment: If $x$ is even, $L(x)=L(x/2)+1$.  If it's odd and greater than $1$, $L(x)=L(3x+1)+1$.  And $L(1)=1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Collatz conjecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collatz_conjecture) has been unsolved for a long time, and that is the best anyone can say about this posted question.